# How do I pass my state from a child component to a parent component, then to another child component of a different parent component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, state

Currently working on a CV Creator as a mini React project, these are my current Components:

Creator
Form
Input
CvDisplay
(DisplayComponents)

I have a state in my Input component that updates upon every change in the input box, this is a simplified example of the component:

```
export default function Input() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const handleInputChange(e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleInputChange} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am trying to get the inputValue state to the Creator component, and then into the CvDisplay component, so when the inputValue changes from the Input component, the changes will display in real time in the CvDisplay component. An example of it being done would be here: https://cv-app-eta.vercel.app/

Beginner here so I would appreciate any advice, thank you!

I tried using a callback function, but it did not work as expected as there are multiple Input Components in the Form component.

Also tried lifting up the state, but could not manage to make it work as it's technically a "grandparent to child" component instead of a parent to child component.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the context api or redux toolkit to do this in easy way but as you say that you are a beginner you can make the inputValue state in the parent component and then pass it as a prop to the child component.